# gprof profiling on Beagle Bone Black

Tags: c++, c, profiling, beagleboneblack

I am trying to profile an Algorithm on Beagle BoneBlack using gprof(Pretty big Algo which has lots of sub algorithms called.I am using both C & Cpp Files).

I have compiled the code with "-pg" option and i do get the gmon.out. When i run it, it shows the call graph of the functions.
But the problem is it does not list all the functions and its corresponding time which i require the most. I am sure they are few hundreds of ms in run time.

1) Is there any other better method for profiling on BeagleBone? I used system clock but wanted to go for some profiling method.
2) The sample count in my case is 0.01seconds. Is there any way to change it to milliseconds and check?
Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [*This is what I do.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)

Comment: Thanks. At the moment, I am not able to debug the code on Beagle bone unfortunately. So no breakpoints and halts. Any best method to profile?

Comment: Well, I typed "debug beaglebone black" into Google, and a bunch of stuff came up, including something about [*GDBServer.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmGe0s59g_o).